# Can't expand environment variables with C# (using Windows 7)

Tags: c#, environment-variables

I am trying to expand microsoft environment variables I found on this microsoft page: https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd560744(v=ws.10).aspx

The C# function I am using is: `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%SYSTEM32%")`
My final goal is to add the expanded environment variable to a combobox. I want to do it like this: `this.destinationDirComboBox.Items.Add(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%SYSTEM32%"));`

The problem is that the only environment variables that will get expanded are  %TEMP% and %WINDIR%. All others will show the environment variable without expanding it, e.g. %SYSTEM32% instead of C:\Windows\System32.My goal is for it to show C:\Windows\System32.

What I've tried:

- Adding a user environment variable by going to
  Computer->Properties->Advanced System Settings->Environment
  Variables->add a new user environment variable. It works only on my
  own command line, but not in the C# code.
- Tried to add a system environment variable and I'm not sure if I did it wrong or if it didn't work. Didn't find much information on
  how it goes.
- Checked the value of the Windows PATH registry key.

What could be the cause of the problem? How can I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open a command prompt and check the existing ENV variables with `set` command.
Afaik sth. like SYSTEM32 is no standard for Windows, but it is defined by WINDIR+"System32" if you are really searching only for that location.

different approach:

```
this.destinationDirComboBox.Items.Add(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System));// -> c:\windows\System32
```

check this for more paths and destinations:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop); // -> c:\Users\UserX\Desktop
```

this Docs will help you: [MSDN Specialfolder docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Environment.SpecialFolder);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true)

Comment: Is there a way to define an environment variable without doing it by manually adding strings as in WINDIR+"System32"? The problem is, it won't work, because I want the application to show the user the right path on his/her own machine, not the one I defined by adding strings. E.g. the path to a user's desktop should include the USERNAME of the computer, which needs to be dynamically retrieved.

Comment: there is surely such an way, but I do not unserstand, why you want it? I thought your goal ist to fill a combox with some path information. Pls check my updated answer

Comment: Thank you so much - it worked. The only folder path I couldn't find was quicklaunch, but that's just one of many, doesn't matter. You saved my day!